# I have some values in brackets I need to sum the values in ssrs

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2012, ssrs-tablix

I HAVE VALUES LOOKS LIKE BELOW

1.(-250.00)
2. 1293.01
3. (-3567.78)
I NEED SUM OF these values using ssrs expression can anyone please helpme

Comment: Are you sure those brackets are not just formated negative numbers in SSRS? In which case, you can just add them with a +

Comment: Are these 3 values that you numbered ( **1.** `(-250.00)`) or is numbering in the same field as the amounts (`1.(-250.00)`)? Is this 3 records or a single record with all 3/6 numbers (`1.(-250.00) 2. 1293.01 3. (-3567.78)`)?

Comment: It's not a single record I have number that Row wise

Comment: 1.(-&235.675),  2.  343.65,  3.(-$5427.78) like these

Comment: I have tried use add total but I'm getting #error

Answer (score 0):

I think the only way to get rid of the brackets is to REPLACE them and then use VAL to convert the resulting number into a number format. VAL doesn't seem to work on it's own like I thought it would.

```
=SUM(REPLACE(REPLACE(Fields!AMOUNT.Value, "(", ""), ")", ""))
```

Comment: 1.(-$123.866) ,2.(-$653.757),3.  4368.86 looks like this  valuesI have tried but I'm getting #error